# Use SUM With Update & CTE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, update, cte

I am attempting to Use the `SUM()` function with an update query and I am getting an error of

> Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Procedure PYES, Line 144
>   Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

I am not sure how to re-write this in order to achieve my desired result.  Can someone please provide assistance?

```
;WITH CTE As
(Select pkID,serviceman, jv
 FROM OPENQUERY(XXX.XX.XXX.XXX,
                'Select
                    jb.pkID As pkID
                    ,cm.cn As serviceman
                    ,jb.jv As jv
                    FROM arica jb
                    INNER JOIN serviceman cm
                    ON jb.spID = cm.spID
                    INNER JOIN salesperson sp
                    ON jb.uqID = sp.uqID
                    INNER JOIN jointca js
                    ON jb.css = js.sid
                    INNER JOIN jart jp
                    ON jp.pkID = jb.pkID
                    WHERE jb.css IN (''R'',''H'',''p'',''S'',''O'',''N'')
                    GROUP BY jb.pkID, jb.jv,cm.cn') v
WHERE jv > 0)
UPDATE t
SET INP = SUM(ISNULL(INP,0)+ISNULL(SUM(jv),0))
FROM tertiarydata t
INNER JOIN CTE cte
ON t.pkID = cte.pkID;
```

**EDIT**
Thanks to the dupe by @SP_BlitsErik - I modified my code to the below - but that returns multiple entries for the field `serviceman` I want to only return 1 row for each `serviceman` listed

```
;WITH CTE As
(Select pkID,serviceman, jv
 FROM OPENQUERY(XXX.XX.XXX.XXX,
                'Select
                    jb.pkID As pkID
                    ,cm.cn As serviceman
                    ,jb.jv As jv
                    FROM arica jb
                    INNER JOIN serviceman cm
                    ON jb.spID = cm.spID
                    INNER JOIN salesperson sp
                    ON jb.uqID = sp.uqID
                    INNER JOIN jointca js
                    ON jb.css = js.sid
                    INNER JOIN jart jp
                    ON jp.pkID = jb.pkID
                    WHERE jb.css IN (''R'',''H'',''p'',''S'',''O'',''N'')
                    GROUP BY jb.pkID, jb.jv,cm.cn') v
WHERE jv > 0)
, uCTE as (
  select pkID,serviceman, sumJV=sum(jv)
    from cte
    group by serviceman,pkID
)
Select * from uCTE
```

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik - see my edit.  I am now having multiple rows return for each salesman.  I want aggregated totals i.e. one row for each salesman.

Comment: Then why are you also grouping by pkID? If you have two people with serviceman = 'Fred', and one has pkID = 7 and the other has pkID = 12, which one do you want? You need to tell SQL Server how to decide. Right now you're telling it to return both.